# unload a user control in Asp.net using C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I want to unload a user control
control.dispose()  & remove is not working.
Please help

Comment: how are you trying to remove the control and how are you adding it in the first place. Please post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to remove any *event handlers* associated with your control before removing the control from your form or panel and then dispose it.